# Sunspot Solr Rails geosearch is failing with undefined method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, geospatial, sunspot

I'm new to using the Sunspot gem. I have it installed and correctly indexing and querying. However, I am now trying to bound the search parameters by including geo search. My database table that is indexed by SOLR has latitude and longitude fields but I'm unable to get geo-search working.

Here's what I have in my model:

```
  searchable do
    .
    .
    .
    double :latitude, :as => "lat"
    double :longitude, :as => "lon"
    location (:location) { Sunspot::Util::Coordinates.new(lat, lon) }
  end
```

However when I run the rake task to reindex it fails with the following:

```
undefined method `lat' for #<Product:0x1076e6650>
```

I've also tried:

```
latlon(:location){ Sunspot::Util::Coordinates.new(lat, lon) }
```

and

```
location(:location){ Sunspot::Util::Coordinates.new(:latitude, :longitude) }
```

I've tried various different options such as passing in :latitude and :longitude rather than lat, lon but I seem to be running into different errors each time.

I've got the following gems installed: 
sunspot (2.0.0, 1.3.3, 1.2.1)
sunspot_rails (1.3.3, 1.2.1)
sunspot_solr (2.0.0)

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: I realized that I needed to update to sunspot_rails 2.0.0 and sunspot 2.0.0 but that has not solved the problem either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Here's the correct way to do it:

```
searchable do
.
.
.
double :latitude
double :longitude
location (:location) { Sunspot::Util::Coordinates.new(latitude, longitude) }
end
```